# What is the fastest way to get a list of errors from a C# solution with MSBuildWorkspace?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, compilation, roslyn

I'm using MSBuildWorkspace and need to analyze a C# solution for errors. I don't need actual compilation results (files), just the errors.

What is the fastest way to get a list of errors from a solution with MSBuildWorkspace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the solution and then iterate through your projects and find all errors. This doesn't create any files (ie. no IL is emitted) but it does require most of the rest of the compiler pipeline (lexing, parsing, binding etc.).

```
//Replace with the correct filepath
var filePath = @"SomeSolution.sln";
var msbws = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var soln = await msbws.OpenSolutionAsync(filePath);

foreach(var proj in soln.Projects)
{
    var name = proj.Name;
    var compilation = await proj.GetCompilationAsync();
    var errors = compilation.GetDiagnostics().Where(n => n.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error).ToList();
    // TODO: Do something with the errors
}
```

If you know which project you'd like to open (and are fine ignoring others) you could also use [`OpenProjectAsync`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild/MSBuild/MSBuildWorkspace.cs,36ad4ad06a6f8079).

Comment: My research into Roslyn actually started with your tutorials a few years ago, thanks for the answer :-). This code is what I currently use, except I order projects for compilation with ```solution.GetProjectDependencyGraph().GetTopologicallySortedProjects()``` and also check diagnostics for ```.IsSuppressed```.

Answer (score 1):

[JoshVarty's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300908/joshvarty) [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51829636/4857601) will work but you may run into trouble correctly locating the version of MSBuild in order for the analysis to run.  Here would be a complete example against the newest roslyn apis (version 2.9):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Build.Locator;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbols;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args) {
        // Attempt to set the version of MSBuild.
        var visualStudioInstances = MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances().ToArray();
        var instance = visualStudioInstances.Length == 1
            // If there is only one instance of MSBuild on this machine, set that as the one to use.
            ? visualStudioInstances[0]
            // Handle selecting the version of MSBuild you want to use.
            : SelectVisualStudioInstance(visualStudioInstances);

        Console.WriteLine($"Using MSBuild at '{instance.MSBuildPath}' to load projects.");

        // NOTE: Be sure to register an instance with the MSBuildLocator 
        //       before calling MSBuildWorkspace.Create()
        //       otherwise, MSBuildWorkspace won't MEF compose.
        MSBuildLocator.RegisterInstance(instance);

        using (var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create()) {
            // Print message for WorkspaceFailed event to help diagnosing project load failures.
            workspace.WorkspaceFailed += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Diagnostic.Message);

            var solutionPath = args[0];
            Console.WriteLine($"Loading solution '{solutionPath}'");

            // Attach progress reporter so we print projects as they are loaded.
            var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath, new ConsoleProgressReporter());
            Console.WriteLine($"Finished loading solution '{solutionPath}'");

            // Print the number of errors found for each project
            foreach(var project in solution.Projects) {
                var name = project.Name;
                var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();
                var errors = compilation.GetDiagnostics().Where(n => n.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);
                Console.WriteLine($"project '{name}' contained '{errors.Count()}');
            }
        }
    }

    private static VisualStudioInstance SelectVisualStudioInstance(VisualStudioInstance[] visualStudioInstances) {
        Console.WriteLine("Multiple installs of MSBuild detected please select one:");
        for (int i = 0; i < visualStudioInstances.Length; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Instance {i + 1}");
            Console.WriteLine($"    Name: {visualStudioInstances[i].Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"    Version: {visualStudioInstances[i].Version}");
            Console.WriteLine($"    MSBuild Path: {visualStudioInstances[i].MSBuildPath}");
        }

        while (true) {
            var userResponse = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(userResponse, out int instanceNumber) &&
                instanceNumber > 0 &&
                instanceNumber <= visualStudioInstances.Length) {
                return visualStudioInstances[instanceNumber - 1];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Input not accepted, try again.");
        }
    }

    private class ConsoleProgressReporter : IProgress<ProjectLoadProgress> {
        public void Report(ProjectLoadProgress loadProgress) {
            var projectDisplay = Path.GetFileName(loadProgress.FilePath);
            if (loadProgress.TargetFramework != null) {
                projectDisplay += $" ({loadProgress.TargetFramework})";
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"{loadProgress.Operation,-15} {loadProgress.ElapsedTime,-15:m\\:ss\\.fffffff} {projectDisplay}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen information on MSBuildLocator, however, I tested not having it and solution worked both on my home machine and work machine so far. Can you give an example, when not using MSBuildLocator causes an issue?

Comment: If you have two VS installations on the same machine (or two MSBuild installs).  Also, the above example will work even if you are not in a developer command prompt

Comment: Also the example above will print out loading errors (missing reference or projects) where-as the other will silently fail.